# Switch off autocorrect on Xamarin forms 'Entry' component

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Need to switch off auto correct and spell check on the `Entry` component in Xamarin Forms(UITextField equivalent of Cocoa)

Is there any property to do this?

Comment: I think a Xamarin.Forms update (not sure which version) may have made this easier since the original post as the the Entry now has a IsSpellCheckEnabled property to control this (and also related IsTextPredictionEnabled property). See [here](http://https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry) for further info Unfortunately they don't seem to have extended these new properties to EntryCell which is where I would like to disable spell checking. Anyone have an easier suggestion that creating a custom renderer? I am hoping for an XAML only solution if possible,

Answer (score 16):

Set `IsTextPredictionEnabled` property to `False`

```
<Entry Text="YOUR TEXT" IsTextPredictionEnabled="False"/>
```

Comment: This seems like the simplest way to turn off autocorrect for an Entry control :)

Answer (score 4):

Can be done by setting the `Keyboard` property

```
selectedEntry.Keyboard = Keyboard.Create(KeyboardFlags.CapitalizeSentence | KeyboardFlags.Spellcheck);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need to achieve, you may also set the Keyboard property of the Entry tag to Chat, Email, Numeric, Plain, Telephone, Text, and Url. Example:

```
<Entry Text="{Binding EmailAddressInput}" Keyboard="Email"/>
```