# Windows 10 Mobile doesn't respect KeyboardFlags.None

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, win-universal-app

I have a Xamarin.Forms app. On Windows 10 Mobile `KeyboardFlags.None` on an Entry is not respected. "Mistakes" are auto-corrected.

On All platforms besides Windows 10 Mobile `KeyboardFlags.None` is respected, and there's no auto-correct. (i.e. Windows 10 non-mobile, Android, iOS.)

Is there a way to fix this for Windows 10 Mobile?

Comment: You must have checked this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44018011/switch-off-autocorrect-on-xamarin-forms-entry-component

Comment: @GaurangDave Thanks. But what I'm using (`KeyboardFlags.None`) is supposed to include removing those mentioned there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the `Xamarin.Forms` GitHub repo, you can see the predictions and spell-checking disabling is implemented in the code itself for both [`Entry`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/96e01cc3fbeb96f1450b52fa72f4d8a970a24eb1/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/EntryRenderer.cs#L169) and [`Editor`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/96e01cc3fbeb96f1450b52fa72f4d8a970a24eb1/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/EditorRenderer.cs#L163), as well as you say it is actually working on UWP on desktop, so this might likely be a bug in Windows 10 Mobile instead.

I would suggest trying this on a blank UWP project if there is a `InputScope`, `IsTextPredictionEnabled` and `IsSpellCheckEnabled` combination that does the trick on mobile as well, because these three should be the only ones to affect the touch keyboard (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox#use-a-text-box-with-the-touch-keyboard)). You could then create a custom class and custom UWP renderer with the hardcoded values.

Comment: `IsSpellCheckEnabled` was enough in a simple UWP app. So it's probably a bug in Xamarin. Thanks.

Comment: That is very weird, it should work the same way on desktop and mobile for UWP, Xamarin does not make difference between the two in most places. Can you please file a bug on Xamarin Bugzilla?